# Show that $I$ is contained in every maximal ideal of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a non-zero commutative ring with $1$. Show that if $I$ is an ideal of $R$ such that $1+a$ is a unit in $R$ for all $a$ in $I$. Then $I$ is contained in every maximal ideal of $R$.

Comment: Where is the prime ideal part involved in the question?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. It is important here to know that this website is not to solve a homework question. Moreover it is important to show us your own work, where you get stucked so that we could help you.

Comment: Not involved in this question but I took this from a chapter of a prime and maximal Ideals. NeerajKumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ be a maximal ideal, $a \in I$ and assume $a \notin M$. Since $M$ is maximal, we find $b$, such that $ab=1 \mod M$. Now have a look at the element $1-ab$. Is it contained in $M$? Is it a unit?