# $R\neq0$ com ring w/ 1.If $I$ is an ideal of $R$ such that $1+a$ is a unit in $R$ for all $a\in I$ then $I$ is contained in every maximal ideal of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Question: Let $R$ be a nonzero commutative ring with $1$.  If $I$ is an ideal of $R$ such that $1+a$ is a unit in $R$ for all $a\in I$ then $I$ is contained in every maximal ideal of $R$.

My apporoach: This question is asked here [Show that $I$ is contained in every maximal ideal of $R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1468413/show-that-i-is-contained-in-every-maximal-ideal-of-r), but I approach it a similar, but different way, and I just want to see if it works:

Suppose $M$, maximal, which does not contain $a$.  Thus, $M\subset I+M=R$.  Let $b\in M$, then $a+b=1$, since $1\in R$.  Then, $b=1-a\in 1+(a)\in M$, a contradiction. Hence, $I\subseteq M$, as wanted.

I suppose I couldn't conclude the problem based on the hint, but I'm sure there was only one or two more lines.

Comment: Is $a+b=1$ for every $b \in M$? for some $b \in M$? How does this follow from $I+M=R$? I think you should be more clear with the writing. Also, $1+(a) \in M$ doesn't make any sense! $1+(a)$ is a subset of $R$, not an element.

Comment: @azif00 Since $1\in R$, and $M$ is proper in $I+M$, there must exist a $b\in M$ such that for $a\in I$, $a+b=1$.  Would that be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Key*: If an ideal of $R$ contains a unit, the ideal must be $R$.

*Proof*: Suppose that there exists a maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ which does not contain $I$. Then $\mathfrak m$ is properly contained in $I+\mathfrak m$, and then $I+\mathfrak m = R$ by maximality. Thus we can find $a\in I$ and $b \in \mathfrak m$ such that $1=a+b$. By assumption, $b=1-a$ is a unit, so $\mathfrak m = R$, and this is a contradiction.

Comment: I am revisiting this, and I have a quick question: we are assuming that 1+a is a unit.... But here, you assume that 1-a is a unit... we can't assume that, can we?

Comment: @User7238 Hi! Notice that $a \in I$ implies that $-a \in I$ too. Now, since we are assuming $\forall x \in I\,(1+x \textrm{ is a unit})$, we can conclude that $1+(-a)=1-a$ is a unit.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply, I really do appreciate it!  And that makes perfect sense.  Thank you so much!!!